# Hardcoded date required instead of automated date minus 1

Tags: sql

```
case when "DocDate"<=CAST(ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE,-1) as date) then sum("TransValue") else 0
```

I need a hardcoded date instead of (CURRENT_DATE) so that my user can able to fetch the report on all days with actual result for that particular date.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: `case when DocDate <= '07-12-1942' then whatever`?   Just hard code the date? If there's more to your question than that please [edit] it to explain.

Comment: So what's the question? Just replace `current_date` with the hardcoded date.

Comment: case when DocDate <= '07-12-1942' then whatever.............................                                                         I need a hardcoded date -1... is it possible      How to subtract date from hardcoded date

Comment: In standard SQL: `date '2020-01-25' - 1` or simply `date '2020-01-24'`

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL: `date'2020-01-25' - interval'1' day`.